# Why is it that there is no VeraCrypt in the Linux Mint software repository?

Tags: linux-mint

I was honestly shocked to see "no matching package found" when searching for "veracrypt" in the software manager in Linux Mint.

I need VeraCrypt to transfer files securely in a USB stick from my Mint computer to my Windows one (which already runs VeraCrypt).

Why is VeraCrypt lacking? It's not like TrueCrypt just died the other day -- it's been years and years now with VeraCrypt having taken over after TrueCrypt.

Installing it manually from their website may be *possible*, but a nightmare to deal with...

Also: There was not one single review/rating for Bitcoin Core in the same package manager... This, in combination with my VeraCrypt issue, really makes me feel like I'm doing something unusual/weird. Although both should be standard tools for "Minters"...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the original TrueCrypt license which many don't consider to be a free license which means VeraCrypt (which is licensed under Apache License and TrueCrypt License) can't be included in repositories -- see Debian's [Software that can't be packaged](https://wiki.debian.org/Software%20that%20can%27t%20be%20packaged) and the [ITP bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=814352) (Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu which is based on Debian so same rules applies to Mint too). For example Fedora also has the same problem with VeraCrypt license, see [Forbidden items](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Forbidden_items?rd=ForbiddenItems#TrueCrypt) on Fedora Wiki.

If you only want to be able to use TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt devices on your system without creating them, you can use `cryptsetup` which also supports these devices:

```
sudo cryptsetup tcryptOpen /dev/<path> <name>
```

or you can use [zulucrypt](https://mhogomchungu.github.io/zuluCrypt/) which is available for Mint and also has GUI.